# How to copy file from folder to another folder with Windows Service C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

How to copy file from folder to another folder with Windows Service C#

I try this code to copy file every 30 sec. But time loop is fine, So copy can't be done.
So I use Visual Studio 2012. I will install Windows Service with command line.
How do I fix this code.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using TestWindowService;

namespace TestCopy
{
    public partial class Copy : ServiceBase
    {
        private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        private System.Timers.Timer timer1 = null;
        public Copy()
        {
           InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //File.Copy(@"C:\input\*.*", @"D:\output\*.*");
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Test window service started");
            timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
            this.timer1.Interval = 30000; //every 30 secs
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = "C:\\INPUT\\";
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            String output_dir = "D:\\OUTPUT\\";
            String output_file = Path.Combine(output_dir, e.Name);
            File.Copy(e.FullPath, output_file);
            // File.Copy() works here
            Library.WriteErrorLog("File copy success");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);                 
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Test window service stopped"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to use try catch block and find is there any exception while copy file

Comment: I realize you're asking a question about a Windows service, but have you considered the `robocopy` command?  It has facilities to do what it appears you're trying to do with this code.  And it works.  You'll find much more about it on this MS Technet page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding handler to the `FileSystemWatcher.Created` every 30 seconds.

If I understand correctly, you want to perform the copying every 30 seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using TestWindowService;

namespace TestCopy
{
    public partial class Copy : ServiceBase
    {
        private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        private System.Timers.Timer timer;
        private ConcurrentQueue<FileInfo> lastCreated;

        public Copy()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 30000; //every 30 secs
            timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => CopyFiles();

            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = "C:\\INPUT\\";
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            //schedule the file for copying on the next tick
            watcher.Created += (s, e) => lastCreated.Enqueue(new FileInfo(e.FullPath));
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Enabled = true;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Library.WriteErrorLog("Test window service started");
        }

        private void CopyFiles()
        {
            String output_dir = "D:\\OUTPUT\\";

            FileInfo fi;
            while (lastCreated.TryDequeue(out fi))
                if (fi.Exists)
                    fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(output_dir, fi.Name));

            Library.WriteErrorLog("File copy success");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            timer.Enabled = false;

            //empty the queue
            FileInfo fi;
            while (!lastCreated.IsEmpty)
                lastCreated.TryDequeue(out fi);

            Library.WriteErrorLog("Test window service stopped");
        }
    }
}
```